# Giving the dimensions of after declaring c++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, declaration

I want to give the dimensions of the vector after declaring it through some other function.

This is because i will come to know the dimensions of vector afterwards.

Is there any way i can do that without using loops.

e.g

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>my_vector;

........
........
........
```

and down in some other function i will declare the dimensions of it.

```
my_vector(2,5);
```

something like that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_vector = std::vector< std::vector<int> >(2, std::vector<int>(5));
```

or in C++11 as Xeo notes:

```
my_vector = {2, std::vector<int>(5)};
```

I think this approach is better than resize, because if you change the size several times, you might end up with a jagged matrix:

```
my_vector.resize(1, std::vector<int>(3));
my_vector.resize(2, std::vector<int>(5));
```

Now row one is 3 elements and row two is 5 elements.

Comment: In C++11, you can make this a lot shorter thanks to list-initialization: [`my_vector = {2, std::vector<int>(5)};`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/eaa55f241fcf82c2d2b32ce10eab2976).

Comment: @Xeo Or `my_vector.assign(2, std::vector<int>(5))` which works in C++03 as well.

Answer (score 3):

`my_vector.resize(2, std::vector<int>(5));`

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/8a8da7129cb600e2539423fbb6167ec0)